# How do I remember where each note is on the piano if I looked at the sheet music?

Tags: piano

I am learning the piano by myself and I want to remember where each note is. I preferably use do re mi fa sol la si(ti) as the musical notation, if that is necessary, as I could probably only remember like that.

Comment: It’s not quite clear what you mean by “where each note is”. Do you mean how do you make your fingers play the correct piano keys when you’re not looking at them? I’m afraid that’s mainly a matter of practice and experience to build the muscle memory and kinesthetic sense.

Comment: Do you know how to read the pitch letters for the various clefs? If the sheet music notates a middle C, which is one ledger line below the staff using a G clef, you play the middle C of the piano. If the key is C major, that middle C will also be solfege DO. Do you already know those things? It isn't clear what part you don't know.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it's easiest to forget the names of the notes for a while, and just learn how to find the positions on keyboard based on sheet music. The connection between the staves and the piano keyboard is really simple: one white key for one position on staff. If there's a sharp, use the next black key to the right, and if there's a flat use the next black key to left. A good starting point is to remember just the location of different Cs (or Dos if you like it more) on the staves and count from there. After you do the counting exercise a few times, you will start to remember other locations too.

The same goes for scales and chords: When you see an ascending or descending row or dots, you don't have to read each of them, just to recognize it's a scale, and when you become familiar with different shapes of stacks of dots, you can play the chords without thinking what they are called.

Answer (score 1):

Remembering where **each** note is is virtually impossible with 88 notes to choose from, looking at the music involved!

However, you don't need to remember each and every one, as there's a pattern that repeats several times up and down the piano keyboard, and the two staves in the music written for it only encompasses around half of those! Good news so far.

Every note on the piano has its own special place, and it works best alphabetically. Your do-re-mi *may* be more familiar to you, but it probably will slow you down here. Firstly, there are two do-re-mi systems, fixed do and movable do. Fixed do *may* help, as that means each and every C note is the white key to the left of the pair of black ones. At least that will give you a start to navigate your way round.

If, quite possibly, you are familiar with *movable do*, it won't help much: that one means the root of every key, though a different note, is called do. Quite confusing for a beginner.

So, let's hope it's fixed do (or C). Travelling up the keyboard, it's sequential, C, D, E, F (left of the 3 black keys), G, A, B, and back to left of the next black pair, another C. Using fixed do, the same idea exists, but substitutes tonic sol-fa names for the letters. Just hope you're not using the German system which incorporates another letter - H.

That's all the piano part, nearly. Using letters only, a good way to familiarise with where each lives is to make up words, and play those words. As in DAD, BADGE, CABBAGE, DEAF, BEEF, and so on, until you can look at a word and play it straight off. Black keys can be ignored for now - they don't play this game. For now, it doesn't really matter which octave you play each letter in, it's fun to mix 'n' match. But familiarisation of the instrument is an important, and in some ways detached part of learning music - where each note lives.

As far as the dots on the sheet are concerned, there is correlation. With 2 staves of 5 lines, it helps to consider that **middle C** is in fact in the middle. It has its own little line - no permanent one. When needed, it has a 'leger line' under the treble, or above the bass clef.

From that datum point, it's not too difficult to extrapolate where on the staves the other notes live. The oft-used mnemonic upwards for the dots on the treble clef lines EGBDF is 'Every Good Boy Deserves (something beginning with F), the spaces revealing FACE. In the bass clef, spaces reveal All Cows Eat Grass, unsurprisingly. Of course, it will be more memorable for your own silly sentence to be utilised.

I hope all that's a good starter in response to what I think the question asks. Take it all slowly, and *get a good teacher*!

Comment: I would argue that it is quite possible to remember where each note on the piano is. This is an essential thing for sightreading sheet music, as you often cannot look at the music and both hands at the same time, so you’ll rely on knowing where the notes are.

Comment: @Lazy - I meant outside of the usual two staves.

Comment: I think we’re speaking about the same thing :)

Comment: Some clues in the question suggest that the OP is in a place where fixed-do is the norm for referencing pitches. I'm guessing based on a few non-standard phrases that hint that English is not their first language (though they're certainly more fluent than I am in any other language!), and about the only places that use letters are English-speaking. It might confuse things to bring moveable do and letter-names into it.

Comment: @AndyBonner - it well might. But the situation does need to be aired. As on a couple of sites here, it would be helpful for OP to reveal location. Here is one such.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to playing the piano, LeninYT!

Are you wanting to 'play by ear' or do you have plans for reading musical scores?

Either way there are seven letter names for the white keys A-B-C-D-E-F-G. The black keys take their names from the white keys by using # & b's. (but don't be concerned about that now :)

Notice the pattern of two black/three black keys. Here's a ditty: "hey dum diddle, D's in the middle, D's in the middle of the two black keys".

Now you know where all the D's are, you can figure out the rest of the music alphabet moving from D to the right = E-F-G-A-B-C or down from D = C-B-A-G-F-E.

BTW, I would recommend using letter names instead of solfeg but you could indeed substitute do re mi fa sol la ti for the CDEFGAB notes.

Hope this helps answer your question! Have a great time exploring!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you are using a piano lesson book, or if you can already read music.  Any good tutor book would teach you how read music and where the corresponding notes are on the piano.  I recommend you try to learn the note names as A-G.  That's more standard on the piano than Do-Ti.  You have to learn two clefs - treble and bass.  This will take time and effort.  You should be sitting pretty much in front of the note Middle C, so that's a good reference point to start with.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the OP is in a country in which pitches are referred to using fixed-do solfege rather than letter names.